# Create a new column with the number of unique occurances by date (groupby 2 conditions - in a timeseries)

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried various group by methods I would like to add a new column 'product-locations' which calculates the total number of  'store locations' for a specific 'product code' on a given date. Basically, how many total number stores is a specific product selling in on any given day. My dataframe should look like this, with 'store-locations' added as a new column.

| date | store_location | product_code | store_locations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 | Store-A | 100 | 3 |
| 2017-01-01 | Store-B | 100 | 3 |
| 2017-01-01 | Store-C | 100 | 3 |
| 2017-01-01 | Store-D | 200 | 1 |
| 2017-01-02 | Store-D | 200 | 1 |

The following for example ignores grouping by date and only takes into account the number if unique products:

`group = df.groupby(['date','store_location','product_code']).size().groupby(level=2).size()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
pvt_coef = df.pivot_table(index=['date','product_code'], aggfunc={'store_location': np.count_nonzero})
pvt_coef.rename(columns={'store_location':'count'}, inplace=True)
pvt_coef.reset_index()
dfcoef = pd.merge(df, pvt_coef, left_on=['date','product_code'], right_on = ['date','product_code'], how='left')
```